# Android in-app shop: How to restore purchases

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-play, andengine

I'm developing an Android game that contains a shop where the player can buy virtual clothes for the main character like t-shirts, hats, trousers etc. These articles can be bought with coins which the player can buy as an in-app-purchase (unmanaged).

**Example:** Assuming that the player buys 100 coins for 1.99$ and then buys 4 different t-shirts using these coins: Now 4 t-shirts are unlocked (stored locally) and the 100 coins are spent. But what if the player buys a new device or wants to play the game on another device? Then the 4 t-shirts cannot be restored, right?

Is there a way to store such purchases to a google account? And what is the best way to restore such in-app purchases? I've read about androids AccountManager and cloud services from google, but it would be nice to achieve what I want using the In-app Billing API from google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are 2 types of products for in-app purchases `Managed` and `Un-managed` a managed product google keeps track of and you can query what the user has purchased while unmanaged product is not held by google

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#producttypes

what you want is a managed product probably and to get all the products that the user has bought all you have to do is query their purchases. Once a managed product if bought by the user it cannot be bought again unless the product if "consumed"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, really appreciate it. I know about the un-managed and the managed products but I'm trying to have a virtual currency (can be bought as in-app purchase and is un-managed) with which the player can buy items. I want to keep track of these bought items. I hope you understand what I mean? Thank you

Comment: Ok so you will have to keep track of how much the user has left of the bought currency on your own server. Google does not provide that sort of in app purchasing managing

Comment: Ah ok, I see. What is the usual situation with apps (games) that have a similar model to mine - does the user usually loose his savegame when he changes his device? I can imagine that a lot of users are going to be upset about this? Thank you.

Comment: I cannot speak from experience because i have never done anything like this but i would assume anytime they make a purchase with the coins you also make a call to your server updating the amount the user has left after the purchase was successful

Comment: Thats possible indeed but I think most developers don't have an own server due to the high maintainance costs caused by the huge mass of players. I'm not sure how the compromise of not storing purchases thus not providing the restore option exactly looks like but I think its not worth the effort to set up a server etc... I think it strongly depends on what the general situation is, but I think most games do not provide such a restore option...

Comment: you might be right but there are also options like `Microsoft Azure` or `Google Cloud Platform` or `Amazon Web Services` where you pay for what you use so the costs are not that much. I personally use Amazon for my backend storage

Comment: I've worked with Microsoft Azure in a business enviroment. I really liked it but I'm not sure if setting up a server is not a little bit too much for this... Do you know swarmconnect (android)? Their services are free. Among other things they have a cloud storage that is exactly what I would need. I think I'll have a deeper look into it. Thank you for your input